# Double Outlet, Half Hot, 3-way Switch

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle

I have a project where I need to install two boxes into the ceiling of a basement. Each box will have two outlets, one on a switch and the other always hot. Both boxes will be connected to 3-way switches, one at the top of the stairs and the other at the door leading into the basement, in a single continuous line. I can not figure out how to wire this with both switched and hot outlets on the same circuit.

Comment: Can you post a sketch of the floorplan layout of the switches, receptacles, and fixtures?

Comment: You are doing more than is possible with available cables.  Can you live with that?

Comment: How do you feel about running conduit?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a hard situation. My preferred approach would be to run power into the first switch 3-way box and 12/3 or 14/3 with ground from that one to the other 3-way switch. Then run the switched cable to both ceiling boxes. That takes care of the switched outlets. Then run a 12/2 or 14/2 with grnd to the ceiling outlet boxes from the first 3-way switch box from the hot, before the switch, to both ceiling boxes. That takes care of the always hot outlets.

I like running power into the first of the 3 way switch, /3 to the next 3 way and from there to the fixture boxes.   That way there is no "code taping involved" and pretty straight forward.

Essentially you are going to have to treat this as 2 circuits.  One for the 3-way switched outlets and the other typical outlet connections in parallel from one to the other.

Comment: Thanks, That is what I thought but my "supervisor" was telling me you could do it all with a single 14/3. Glad I am not the only one that doesn't think so. But because I know he is going to ask, what about making each outlet half-hot and linking each section.